# Import a module from a package

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to import a simple package, but it doesn't work.

I have a "package" directory that contains two files:

- `foo.py` (with a function called fct)
- `__init__.py` (with nothing in it)

Here is the content of `tests.py`:

```
import package.foo

foo.fct(7)
```

But it doesn't work.
If I change the import line to `from package.foo import fct`, I can execute the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `import package.foo as foo` or one of the alternatives below ...

```
import package.foo
package.foo.fct(7)
```

or:

```
import package.foo as foo
foo.fct(7)
```

or possibly:

```
from package import foo
foo.fct(7)
```